# css generator to put generated css layout into textarea

Tags: php, plugins, content-management-system

I am developing a Content Manager System using PHP and wonder if there is a css generator i can use as a plugin. The generated code is stored in MySQL database.

I have looked at many of these [here](http://www.aoclarkejr.com/10-really-awesome-css-generators/), but i cant seem to see any i can provide to my users as a plugin.

I want one that creates layouts and can change background. If i cant get one, then how do i create one.

Comment: When you are developing a CMS from scratch, then there is up to now no plugin existing that follows the standards of the CMS. You will need to write all plugins yourself, like the system itself

Comment: if i cant get one then how do i create one to do layout divs and change bg color

Comment: When you don't have the slightest idea how to create a css generator, then you should perhaps first take a bit more time to educate yourself about the topic. It all depends how exactly you want it to work. If you want an on the fly approach, then you need to create an editor, or a list of options for automatic creation and the infuse the generated code into a preview container. Then there would be an option for further editing, or for saving the code to a file. That's it. Not a big deal from the point of complexity, but still a lot of coding work.

Comment: thanks, you gave me an idea which worked for me. I created small template files with css embedded in tags, these files are called into action if selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you cant get any plugin for that, since the page you are designing must be known to you [positioning, font size, etc]

First, Create a complete site with some css which hold layout, like a1.css
then , you can do the same with same attributes with a2.css, a3.css...etc.. [this may be terrible]
or
you can change dynamically by Jquery to generate dynamically , like

```
.css( "padding-left", "+=15" )
```

or  use different frameworks and make it accessible, [LINK](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/27-of-the-best-css-and-html-frameworks-available-to-download/)

hope it gives you an idea!

Comment: i want one to create layouts and change background